# How to solve this error when building PLC4X with Docker

Tags: docker, apache-plc4x, plc4x

When I try to build PLC4X with Docker I obtain an error. I tried to build it from Linux system, and from Linux in Virtual Box (hosted in a Windows machine) and in both cases I obtain an error.

With the Linux machine I obtain this error:

**Step 20/36 : RUN ./mvnw -P with-sandbox,with-boost,with-dotnet,with-python,with-proxies,with-logstash com.offbytwo.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1.MDEP568:go-offline -DexcludeGroupIds=org.apache.plc4x,org.apache.plc4x.examples,org.apache.plc4x.sandbox
---> Running in 58f0d82652e1
/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c ./mvnw -P with-sandbox,with-boost,with-dotnet,with-python,with-proxies,with-logstash com.offbytwo.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1.MDEP568:go-offline -DexcludeGroupIds=org.apache.plc4x,org.apache.plc4x.examples,org.apache.plc4x.sandbox' returned a non-zero code: 126**

When using a Virtual machine (Windows host) with Linux I obtain this error:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

I don't understand what happen. Is this  error the same in both cases? How can I fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Linux Distro are you running?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu. The only way I could succesfully build plc4x from the Dockerfile was by commenting that line.

Comment: Hi ... and sorry for the late response. Think we should integrate the Dockerfile into our CI build process. We hadn't encountered this problem. I just submitted a fix for that issue ... please try again.

Answer (score 1):

I updated our dependencyManagement to avoid this problem ...  if you update it will probably work this time.

Comment: Thanks, I will try as soon as possible.